# ¿Existe alguna forma de enviar url antes de publicar un artículo?

Tags: wordpress

Quiero desde Wordpress enviar a una persona externa (sin que sepa la contraseña de mi WP) una url de un artículo antes de publicarlo para su revisión.

¿Existe alguna forma de enviar la URL antes de que se publique el artículo?

Comment: ¿Ese WP está online?

Comment: @Orici sí, está online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes compartir un articulo no publicado en WP si la persona no tiene acceso a tu WP. Lo que puedes hacer es crearle un usuario con roll de 'Editor'. Puedes revisar los [roles de usuarios en Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Luego puedes quitarle el acceso si no lo quieres como usuario permanente.

Comment: gracias, el tema es que si creo "su usuario Editor" el deberá estar logueado para poder verlo. Pensé que en WP se podía crear una URL oculta antes de pubicar (como en los videos de Youtube por ejemplo). Gracias!

Comment: Entiendo! También puedes proteger el post con una contraseña. Así no le das acceso a Wordpress pero puedes compartir tu URL! Puedes revisar [este articulo:](https://www.seedprod.com/password-protect-page-wordpress/)

Comment: gracias por la ayuda pero proteger el post con una contraseña ya publica la entrada. Seguro que hay alguna forma de publicar sin que sea publico para todo el mundo solo los que tengan la url como en dropbox, youtube...

Comment: Encontre este [PLUGIN](https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/). Creo que es lo que estas buscando: No requiere acceso a Wordpress y no tienes que publicar el post.

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias! voy a probarlo.